# NodeJS Express Module: 'dotfile' options no working

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, dotfiles

I am running into an oddity when using express.static() to serve static resources. Specifically the `dotfiles` object of the `options` argument is not producing the expected behavior.

Within the express documentation it states :

> ...`express.static` is based on serve-static, and is responsible for serving the static assets...

Furthermore it claims that the supplying `options` argument to `express.static()` should have the same effect as serve-static:

> The optional `options` object can have the following properties.
>
> - dotfiles `option` for serving dotfiles. Possible values are "allow", "deny", and "ignore"; defaults to "ignore".

This is what the serve-static documentation states the `dotfiles` option should dictate:

> - 'allow' No special treatment for dotfiles.
> - 'deny' Send a 403 for any request for a dotfile.
> - 'ignore' Pretend like the dotfile does not exist and call next().

The most concise example I can come up with is the code below. it appears that resources served by serve-static behave as expected, however `express.static()` ignores the options when serving the same resources. That is, despite the fact that argument `{dotfiles : 'allow'}` is being passed to `express.static()`, all requests for resources beginning with '.' return a 404 error.

This is occurring on node version v0.10.25, express version 2.5.8, running on ubuntu server 14.04.1 LTS.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
var finalhandler = require('finalhandler');
var http = require('http');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

app.use('/', express.static('public', {
  dotfiles : 'allow'
}));

app.listen(3001);

var serve = serveStatic('public', {
  dotfiles : 'allow'
});

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  serve(req, res, finalhandler(req, res))
})

server.listen(3002);
```

I expect serve-static and express.static to behave exactly the same. Is there something I am missing? or is this an issue anyone else has encountered?

Comment: So... which one is not working properly for you? express.static or serveStatic ?

Comment: Express version `2.5.8`? Your express version translates to `static` from Connect `1.x`, which doesn't appear to suppport the `dotfiles` argument. The documentation you are probably looking at is for Express `4.x`. Can you upgrade express? If not, you can probably pull in [`serve-static`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static) directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Express `2.5.8` and the documentation you are looking at is likely for `4.x`. `2.5.8` does not have a `dotfiles` option because it uses connect `1.x` which did not support it. Your two options are either:

1. Pull in `serve-static` like you are doing in your example.
2. Upgrade your `express` version. `2.5.8` is quickly approaching 3 years old.

Comment: That was it. Thanks! For some reason I had put version 2.5.8 in the package.json file.